# PHP HTML form session

Tags: php, forms, session

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u']; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
 <form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Register a new user" />
  </form>

   </body>
    </html>
```

So guys I got this and my question is: I want to use sessions to assign the last registered user as the value of the login form. Everything I got runs ok the thing is if I log in for the first time and I have not started a session i get nothing for the U variable and i get an error message. How can I ... avoid that or something. I tried if statement but in the value section it does not accept {} brackets or something. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and assign the session value to a variable instead of using it directly:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['u'])){
   $u = '';
} else {
   $u = $_SESSION['u'];
}

<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $u; ?>" />
```

An alternative solution - though less cleaner and maintainable - is to utilize PHP's ternary operator:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['u']) ? $_SESSION['u'] : ''); ?>" />
```

Simple explanation of the ternary operator

```
($statement ? [if $statement == true] : [$statement == false])
```

Comment: Thank you it works and it makes perfect sense to me. Now I just gotta figure how and when to stop the session and lose the value saved :D. But seriously thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using ternary operator..

try this

```
Name: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['u'])?$_SESSION['u']:''; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['u'])?$_SESSION['u']:''; ?>"
```